# How to call a method with parameters in Apache Camel using Java DSL

Tags: apache-camel

How to call a method in Camel Route using Java DSL? I want to get a compile time error in Eclipse if I am using the wrong signature for method.

```
.bean(Foo.class, "setDetails("1", "Camel")")
```

Here I won't get compile time error for the wrong method signature as method was defined in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, as far as I know, not possible because Camel calls the method through reflection API.

What you can do, is to create constants in `Foo.class` with the method names and then use the constants in the bean calls instead of the hard-coded method name Strings.

But even then, you are of course able to rename a method in the bean without adapting the constant. The functionality would be broken but the compiler would be still happy.

**If the bean is dedicated to Camel routes and under your control**, the best you can do is to refactor the bean.

- Remove the method parameters, set them on the message exchange and inject them with `@Header`, `@Property`
- Split the bean into very small beans with only one method to get rid of the method names

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am not convinced with the statement `not possible because Camel calls the method through reflection API`. This is basic feature and I will try to raise it to Camel team.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
.bean(Foo.class, "setDetails(1, 'Camel')")
```

- If your **first parameter** is of type int just put the number without quotes
- **Second parameter** is String, so you should put String to single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html), from camel 2.9 onwards, you can do pass in an integer and a string as parameters in a method call (using your example) like this:

```
.bean(Foo.class, "setDetails(1, 'camel')")
```

OR

```
.to("bean:Foo?method=setDetails(1, 'camel')")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a compile-time error about something that is evaluated at runtime.  This is simply not possible.